# The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists in Magenot 2.4

Tags: magento2, product, category, url, paths

I have migrated data from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.4.
All things is working well.
But when in open any categories and open Product in Category tab -> then click on reset filter -> search a product and select and then save it it will show me this error.

[image]

I have tried this https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites extension but it doesn't work.

I have checked the db there is only one url in request_path column in url_rewrite table.

Can any one point out what is the issue and how to solve it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a logic problem, URL are generated from product names, and URL must be uniques. From admin panel take the products that are causing the problem, go to **Search Engine Optimization** section and give a custom value to the **URL key** field

Comment: Thanks for the response but if i have 10k producst in store so it would be difficult to do it for every product can you suggest anything else.

Comment: Aren't they just 11 products as shown in the error message screen?

Comment: yes in this ss it is  11 if in future there is more error then i have to do it manually everytime. so that's why i asked for all products

Comment: have you consider adding the sku to the product name? Try with one product to see if it disappear from the errors, if it works you can create a script that do it for all products

Comment: So you mean i need to create a script which will add sku in Product -> SEO -> url key just before the .html tag and then run indexer reindex then all the url is diffrent.
And one more thing i just need to update url_rewrite table or any other table also ?

Comment: That would be more complicated. My idea was a script that rename the "name" field of the products, adding (<sku>) at the end. The generated url key will be like: the-product-name-sku.html

Comment: Actually if you change name and save the product the url key is not updated automatically i think i need to update that also maybe.

Comment: You are right, but the next time Magento will try to generate it, it won't complain about double URL keys

Comment: I have changed the name but still the same issue there i think i need to manually update url of every product

Comment: If you now truncate the url_rewrite table and regenerate them, it should be ok, have a look here https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/URL-rewrites-URL-key-issues/td-p/459330